# Is there a way to figure out what environment variables are needed/used by an executable?

Tags: c++, linux, node.js, environment-variables, root

I've got a C++ program that will run certain very specific commands as root.  The reason this is needed is because another program running under Node.js needs to do things like set system time, set time zone,  etc that require root privileges to accomplish.  I'm using the function execve in C++ to make the system call with root privileges after using the setuid command.  I specifically choose the execve command because I want to wall off the environment so I don't create an environment variable vulnerability.

```
 setuid(0);
 execve(acExeName, pArgsForExec2, pcEnv);
```

What I want to do is find out exactly the pcEnv which is the environment variable list for the program to execute with that my program needs.  For example, if I want to run the tool time-admin as if I was running it from the console, how can I figure out what environment variables it needs.  I know I can print off the environment variables with the command printenv, but that gives me all of them.  I'm quite sure I don't need them all and want as small a subset as possible.

I know I can use them all and then slowly comment each one out and see if it keeps working, but I'd really rather not go that far.

Anyone got a clever way to figure out what environment variables are used by a program?  I should add I'm doing this on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS install.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: unless the programm is doing something funny, ltrace should be useful

Comment: @PlasmaHH by funny you mean something like using the non-standard but commonly implemented third param to `main()`, `char *envp[]`? Because in that case, short of asking the author, reading the documentation, or seeing the actual source, I think the OP is up a creek without a paddle.

Comment: @WhozCraig: exactly, however I see that envptr being much less often used in modern C and general in C++ code than in rather older C code. But all guessing is rarely better than reading the fine manual.

Comment: Extracting `strings` from a binary, barring funny business on the part of the binary, should include all of the environment variables it looks up.  Doing the same with Node.js may be trickier.

Answer (score 2):

There are no general ways of figuring out the environment variables used by some program. For example, one could imagine that a program has some configuration files which gives the name of environment variables.

<sup>Actually many shell like programs (or script interpreters) are doing that.</sup>

More generally, the argument to [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) could be computed. So in theory you cannot guess its possible values. (I might be wrong, but some very old versions of `libc` and of `bash` used to play such tricks; unfortunately, I forgot the details, but sometimes an environment variable with some pid number in its name was used).

<sup>And, as others commented, you might want to use `ltrace` (or play `LD_PRELOAD` tricks), or use `gdb`, to find out how `getenv` is called ...</sup>

And the application might also use the `environ` variable (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) ...) or the third argument to `main` ....

In practice however, a reasonably written program should clearly document all the environment variables it is using....

If you have access to the source code of the program, you could, if it is compiled by GCC, use (the just released version 1.0 of) the [MELT plugin](http://gcc-melt.org/). MELT is a domain specific language to extend GCC and can be used to explore the internal Gimple representations handled by GCC while compiling your program. In particular with its new [`findgimple` mode](http://gcc-melt.org/tutousemelt.html) you could find in one command all the calls to `getenv` with a constant string.